# Catch and logging for irrelevant operations

Tags: java, exception

I've a method to save timing information of each operation:

```
    public void queueTimerInfo(long start, long end, String msg) {
        try {
            timer.queue(start, end, msg);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.info(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I call the above method after each operation. What matters is the operation itself, whereas the timing is just a secondary task. That's why I decided not to do anything when the method fails, except logging it.

But I was always told that logging without managing the exception is a bad practice. So how should I rewrite the above code?

Comment: If this operation is not allowed to disrupt the functionalities of your code, what would you do? throw an Exception?

Comment: add `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` at the end of catch block

Comment: You should simply not rewrite the code

Answer (score 8):

If you know the consequences, i.e. the `timer.queue()` call might be interrupted and not queue the data, and you can live with that, then it is OK to ignore the Exception. As with most rules, you need to know when to break them.

However, I would document your decision with a comment in the catch block, so that whoever maintains the code later knows that not handling the Exception was not an oversight, but a deliberate decision.

Answer (score 5):

> But I was always told that logging without managing the exception is a bad practice

What does "managing" mean? Rethrowing them? Blindly following steps 1, 2, 3 because "zOMG an exception was thrown!!111"?

If you blindly follow best practices and other sorts of advice regardless of your context, then you'll probably end up with really problematic and awkward decisions. Don't do things just because it's best practice. Acknowledge the best practices, but at the same time make sure they actually make sense in your situation.

Ask yourself: does that exception make a difference? Does it break a contract? Does it change the flow of your application? Do you absolutely not want that to  happen and if it does, then the situation is truly exceptional and you should *really* deal with it somehow?

If it doesn't make a difference and so on, then just logging it is perfectly acceptable. It really comes down to your context and to the significance of your exception.

LE: Of course, as Thomas suggests, you may want to document your decision.

Answer (score 4):

`InterruptedException` is special because it does not signal an error.

When a method declares a `InterruptedException` it tells you that it is a blocking method which can be cancelled by interrupting its thread.
Brian Goetz [explains](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/):

> When a method throws InterruptedException, it is telling you that if
>   the thread executing the method is interrupted, it will make an
>   attempt to stop what it is doing and return early and indicate its
>   early return by throwing InterruptedException. Well-behaved blocking
>   library methods should be responsive to interruption and throw
>   InterruptedException so they can be used within cancelable activities
>   without compromising responsiveness.

You should either

- don't catch the exception and add a `throws InterruptedException`
- catch it, do clean up and rethrow it
- when you can't throw it (e.g. in a `Runnable`) call `Thread.getCurrentThread().interrupt();`

If you just swallow the exception you will compromise responsiveness of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap it and rethrow? And then your common exception handler can take care of logging and reporting. And provide context with it if possible.

Comment: Logging the timing via queue should not influence the surrounding code, so rethrow is a bad choice!